# I cannot record sound well in guvcview in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound

Using guvcview to record some video, the sound quality is not good. There is a "Zizi" sound  at the beginning of the voice.  I am recording a video tutorial, so I really need to get better sound quality. My video and microphone is Logitech C930e. It worked well on Ubuntu 20.

Comment: Consider using OBS Studio. It might work better. Of course, it could also be a microphone issue too. But testing with a different app is a pretty easy way to troubleshoot

Answer (score 2):

After some test, I maybe find out the solution:

I installed a simple app called "audio recorder" to test my sound quality. In this app, if I set my format to "OGG Lossy 44KHz", the recorded sound always begins with "Zizi", if choose format "MP3 Lossy 44KHz", the sound quality is acceptable. Very strangely, the sound quality in  guvcview changes with this setting. I tested OBS studio, the sound quality changes with my setting.  I think I should set the default sound codec to some good one.

Another strange thing happens, my OBS scene seems changes after reboot, for example, I crop my camera into a size using "ALT", next time, it changes if I reboot the system. (https://itsfoss.com/switch-xorg-wayland/) My display server is Xorg,  what is the problem?

---

I do not understand why everything works well now, maybe it is because of an auto update, or after I installed VLC and set VLC as the default application.

Now OBS works well, both sound and video seems acceptable now.

Answer (score 1):

This one works decent for ubuntu 22.04 [gnome audio recorder](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/SoundRecorder)

`sudo apt-get install gnome-sound-recorder -y`

this installs `gnome-sound-recorder` trough APT via the commandline.